# Responsive Card with max width issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a responsive card that has a maximum width. On larger screens, the card should expand to occupy the entire available width, while on smaller screens, its width should adjust proportionally to fit the screen space.

Clarification: by adjust its width proportionally, I mean that on smaller screen the card should scale down to fit the screen size. in simple words it means the card is responsive to the screen size.

I tried this. Unfortunatetly, it does not work. Is there a way to achieve this without the use of media queries? Thank you.

```css
.card {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: What does "adjust proportionally" mean? Your requirements aren't clear (and they're a bit opposite to what's more typical, where elements are full-width on _smaller_ devices). Please revise to add detail.

Comment: I added some clarification. Hope it clears things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.card-container` element uses `display: flex` to create a flexible container. The justify-content: center centers the card horizontally within the container.

The .card element has a `max-width` of 300px to ensure that it doesn't exceed a certain width. The flex: 1 property allows the card to expand and occupy the available space within the container while maintaining its maximum width of 300px. This way, the card will adjust its width proportionally on different screen sizes.

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  /* Center the card horizontally */
}

.card {
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    Card content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've built what I initially assumed was desired, but upon rereading I see that it's the opposite.